# Angular 17 form onChange Filter Table Column

Tags: angular

I'm currently coding a new Angular 17 App and I'm fairly new to Angular. I think I'm good with important concepts like Services, Signals, RxJs, etc. The thing I'm struggling with is the Form controls onChange event. It seems that there are many ways to trigger event when a form control value changes and I'm looking for the latest and most efficient way to do it.

The component I made has a mat table display a list of objects from an HTTP Request Observable and I added a form with a textfield for each column to filter each column when the user starts typing. I was testing this way where I subscribed to the fromGroup valueChanges Observable comparing each from control name to the model object properties from the datasource and applying a custom filter predicate.

```
this.filteFormValueChangesSub = formgroup.valueChanges.subscribe(formValues => {
  //Looping filter Form group fields
  for (const formInput in formValues) {
    if(formInput) {
      //Defining a custom predicate to filter fields the data source object
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (object: Object, filter: string) => {
        //Matching the Object properies with the form fields 
        Object.entries(object).forEach(objectProperty  => {
          const propertyName = objectProperty[0];
          const propertyValue = objectProperty[1];
          if (propertyName === formInput) {
            return <boolean> propertyValue.toLowerCase().includes(filter);
          }        
        });
        return false;
      };
      this.dataSource.filter = formInput;
    }
  }
});
```

Do you think that's a good way to trigger a filter on form control change event?

Also do I need to unsuscribe to form valueChanges Observabel onDestroy just like I normally do for HTTP Request Observables?

P.S. Sorry if I'm bad with naming because I'm originally a Java developer.

My code works. I just want to know how someone with experience would proceed.

Comment: Looks ok, depends on your dataSource implementation. You can create a custom operator for readability and reusability, use it that way:

`this.filteFormValueChangesSub = formgroup.valueChanges.pipe(prepareDataSource(this.dataSource)).subscribe();
`


> Also do I need to unsuscribe to form valueChanges Observabel onDestroy just like I normally do for HTTP Request Observables?

Yes. You can use takeUntilDestroy operator as you are using angular 17. https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/takeUntilDestroyed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is YES, you should unsubscribe to valueChanges, but I feel that there's "something" strange in your code.

When we have a mat-table with filter generally

first: You define the `filterPredicate` one unique time
after: You change the property `filter` when the formGroup change

The filterPredicate is executed with each element of the table and the arguments are the "element" and the property "filter"

So, as the property filter is an string, generally you pass a JSON.stringify of the form.value -generally the same properties and the values in lowerCase

```
obs$=forms.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
   const filter={...res}
   Object.keys(res).forEach(key=>{
      if (!res[key])
          filter.delete(key)
      else
          filter[key]=filter[key].toLowerCase();
     })
     return filter;
   }).subscribe((res:any)=>{
      this.dataSource.filter=JSON.stringify(res)
   })
})
```

And you have

```
this.dataSource.filterPredicate=(data:any,filter:string)=>{
   const filter=JSON.parse(filter)
   return Object.keys(filter).reduce((a:boolean,key:string)=>{
      a=a&& filter[key].include(data[key].toLowerCase())
   },true)
   }
})
```